# I need http port forward proxy server golang

Tags: http, https

I need http port forward proxy server golang

Be able to provide  Rest http api

Kind of like

PortForward  Traffic Forwarding

Please tell me the program that can be used directly.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I made a small forward proxy server using fasthttp. Supports http/https/ws/wss etc.

Link: https://github.com/joeky888/fpgo

And here is the minimal core code for anyone end up here:

```golang
func transfer(destination io.WriteCloser, source io.ReadCloser) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            Warn("transfer: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    if _, err := io.Copy(destination, source); err != nil {
        Debug("transfer io closed: %s", err)
    }
}

func handleFastHTTP(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    if err := fastclient.DoTimeout(&ctx.Request, &ctx.Response, timeout); err != nil {
        Error("Client timeout: %s", err)
    }
}

func handleFastHTTPS(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    ctx.Hijack(func(clientConn net.Conn) {
        destConn, err := defaultDialer.DialTimeout(string(ctx.Host()), 10*time.Second)
        if err != nil {
            Error("Dial timeout: %s", err)
            return
        }

        defer clientConn.Close()
        defer destConn.Close()

        go transfer(destConn, clientConn)
        transfer(clientConn, destConn)
    })
}

// request handler in fasthttp style, i.e. just plain function.
func fastHTTPHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    switch string(ctx.Method()) {
    case fasthttp.MethodConnect:
        handleFastHTTPS(ctx)
    default:
        handleFastHTTP(ctx)
    }
}

func main() {
    server := &fasthttp.Server{
        Handler:            fasthttp.CompressHandler(fastHTTPHandler),
        ReadTimeout:        timeout,
        WriteTimeout:       timeout,
        MaxConnsPerIP:      500,
        MaxRequestsPerConn: 500,
        IdleTimeout:        3 * timeout,
        ReduceMemoryUsage:  true,
        CloseOnShutdown:    true,
        Concurrency:        maxConcurrent,
    }

    server.ListenAndServe(addr)
}
```